# Can coral reefs thrive in large freshwater bodies or evolve to adapt in large lakes?

Tags: biology, evolution

How can coral reefs evolve or adapt to be able to thrive in large freshwater bodies?

Comment: This is now a one sentence question. It might be valid, but I feel like more information could be given. What have you looked at yourself? Why do you want freshwater corals? Would they need to compete with the local freshwater life?

Comment: Voting to close. A one-sentence question suggests you've done zero research on your own. You can google "fresh water corals" as a starting point. You also haven't given us any kind of basic constraints: is there magic, or just physics?

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding, we invite you to take our [tour] and read-up in the [help] about our ways. Enjoy the site.

Comment: ? They need to adapt to tolerate lower salinity levels. Corals are not at all exceptional -- there are many kinds of animals which live only in fresh water (e.g., frogs) or only in salt water (e.g., octopusses). Not to mention that most kinds of fish are either fresh-water fish or salt-water fish, with only few kinds of fish which can live in both.